# How to change the version number in iPhone application 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app approved by app store that is version 1.0, and I want to update the app to version 2.0. I changed version to 2.0 in iTunes. It's in the "waitin for upload" state. I have made some code modification in my version 1.0 and changed the bundle version as 2.0. When I am about to upload the appbinary using  xcode, it still shows the version as 1.0. If I m to click the validate button, it gives a message that it's already uploaded. Should I change the bundle identifier? I'd be so grateful if you guys could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the iTunes state "Waiting for Upload"? If not, then you have not yet told itunesconnect that you are ready to upload binary.

Comment: @pengone..yes its in waitin for upload in itunes connect...but still the version shows 1.0 when i m about to upload the binary by xcode(windows-->organizer)....i even changed the bundleverison to 2.0...even in itunes connect its 2.0...should i got to give a new bundle identifer and not to have the 1.o bundle identifier?..

Answer (score 3):

You should update the BundleVersion in your Info.plist file prior to compiling your final release build.

Comment: i ve changed the bundleversion to 2.0 still i m getting 1.0 in the organizer...should i got to change the bundleidentifier

Answer (score 1):

Delete your build folder and/or check your target to make sure you are building your release target and not trying to send an old release build.

Comment: i deleted the build folder and compiled still having the same problem...its like dis i added extra features in my old version 1.0 ....i changed bundleversion to 2.0 when i m about to upload the app using xcode still i m able to see 1.0 and not 2.0....hav any idea...i even gave a build to targets